# Lower bound on function given lower bound on integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If we are given a continuous function $f : [0,1]\to[0,1] $ and $\int_0^1 f dx > \varepsilon$ then can we put a lower bound on the function on some finite union of disjoint intervals such that the sum of their lengths and the bound on the function depend solely on $\varepsilon $. That is, can we find $\delta $ and $a $ as functions of $\varepsilon $ such that there exists a set of $n$ intervals, $\sum_1^n b_i-a_i > \delta $ and $f>a $ at every point of these intervals.

Comment: I suppose only the sum of lengths of intervals is independent of the function, while the intervals themselves can depend on the function?

Comment: Hmmm ... according to Mean Value Th. $\exists x_0 \in \left ( 0,1 \right ):f(x_0)\cdot (1-0)=f(x_0)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx>\varepsilon$. Because $f(x_0)>\varepsilon$ and $f(x)$ is continous, then $\exists V(x_0)$ vicinity of $x_0$ such that $\forall x \in V(x_0): f(x)>\varepsilon$. Or am I missing anything?

Comment: Is there a lower bound on the length of $V(x_0)$ in terms of $\varepsilon$. That is what I want with my question (or the sum of lengths of $V(x_i)$ having this property.

Comment: That is a direct result of the "Sign-preserving property of continuous functions" http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663181/my-proof-of-bolzanos-theorem. It is definitely $>0$ (strictly!) and depends on the function itself.

Comment: I know... I just want to know a lower bound on the length of these intervals in terms of $\varepsilon$

Comment: Just to confirm my "hypothesis" re it "depends on the function", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces ... $f(V(x_0))=M \subset \left \{ f(x) \in [0,1] \mid f(x) >\varepsilon  \right \}$ and $f^{-1}(M)=V(x_0)$ which reads "function of $f$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalization: Suppose $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is Riemann integrable and $\int_0^1 f >\epsilon.$ Then there is a collection of pairwise disjoint open subintervals of $[0,1]$ of equal length, the sum of whose lengths is $> \epsilon/2,$ and such  that $f>\epsilon/2$ on each subinterval.

Proof: For any $n\in \mathbb N$ we consider the uniform partition of $[0,1]$ into $n$ subintervals $I_k$ of length $1/n.$ Since $f$ is Riemann integrable we can choose and fix an $n$ large enough so that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}m_k\cdot\frac{1}{n} > \epsilon,$$

where $m_k = \inf_{I_k}f.$ Let $A= \{k:m_k>\epsilon/2\},B= \{k:m_k\le\epsilon/2\}.$ Then

$$\sum_{k\in A}1\cdot\frac{1}{n} + \sum_{k\in B}(\epsilon/2)\cdot\frac{1}{n} >\epsilon.$$

This implies (throwing away a lot) that

$$|A|\frac{1}{n} + n(\epsilon/2)\frac{1}{n} > \epsilon \implies |A|\frac{1}{n} > \epsilon/2.$$

(Here $|\,\,|$ denotes cardinality.) Thus the sum of the lengths of the subintervals $I_k$ corresponding to $k\in A$ is $> \epsilon/2,$ and since $f >\epsilon/2$ on each such subinterval, we're done. (Take the interiors of these subintervals if you want them disjoint.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an argument using a little bit of measure theory and Lebesgue integration theory. Let $A = \{ x \in [0,1] : f(x) \le \epsilon / 2 \}$ and $B$ its complement in $[0,1]$. Then $\int_A f \le \epsilon / 2$, so $\int_B f > \epsilon / 2$. On the other hand, since $f$ is bounded above by $1$, you get $\int_B f \le \lambda(B)$ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue (length) measure, so $\lambda (B) > \epsilon / 2$. Since $B$ is a relatively open subset of $[0,1]$, it is a countable union of intervals, so you can find finitely many intervals in $B$ with total length $\ge \epsilon / 2$. So you get the result with $a = \delta = \epsilon / 2$.

Comment: Thanks. Why didn't I think of trying to use measure theory even though the chapter is about measure theory?... (though he wants not to use measure theory in the proof, to show the power of Lebesgue integral)

Comment: Why can't we use a similar argument, but with $A=\{x \in [0,1]: f(x) \leq \frac{2 \varepsilon}{3} \}$ and conclude that $a=\frac{2 \varepsilon}{3}$ and $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$?

Comment: @rtybase: You can certainly do that as well, there is no unique $\delta$ and $a$.